# I need to export field "unit" in another json file, if they have a equal "name"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a script that compares 2 JSON files, It takes a name from the first JSON and comparing to another JSON file, and if they don't have an equal "name", the object will be deleted.

Here is a code:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Read the goods JSON file
const goods = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('good.json', 'utf-8'));

// Read the products JSON file
const products = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('products.json', 'utf-8'));

// Create an array of the names of objects in goods
const goodsNames = goods.map(obj => obj.name);

// Filter objects from products that don't have a matching name in goods
const filteredProducts = products.filter(obj => goodsNames.includes(obj.name));

// Write the filtered and sorted products back to the products file with formatting for readability
fs.writeFileSync('products.json', JSON.stringify(filteredProducts, null, 4), 'utf-8');
```

I need to export a field "unit" from good.json, another JSON, and put the field in objects with equals "name".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]  (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: **If** you end up having to post a question, please be sure to include all the necessary detail for people to help you solve it. For instance, show us what a **minimal** example of the two JSON files is, and show us what end result you'd want.

Comment: Side note: The code you have for reading those files is fine, but just FYI, you could also do `const goods = require("good.json");`. Node.js's CJS loader knows how to load JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this above the last line in your code:

```
filteredProducts.forEach(product => {
  const matchingGood = goods.find(good => good.name === product.name);
  product.unit = matchingGood.unit;
});
```